# Path injection in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Let's assume I have an API call that expects the prefix of a file name and then concatenates a suffix with an extension to it:

```
var fileName = prefix + "_suffix.txt";
var folderPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "SubDir", fileName);
returnFile.ReadAllText(folderPath));
```

The API is called like this:

```
http://www.example.com/api/readFile?prefix=<prefix>
```

Off the bat an attacker can obviously inject various combinations of `..\` to browse arbitrary files that end with `_suffix.txt`, but is it possible to inject some sort of path termination character(s) that allow me to browse any arbitrary file on disk by ignoring the concatenated suffix?

To make things clearer, the API call is meant to return the contents of the file:

```
<app root dir>\SubDir\<prefix>_suffix.txt
```

Is it possible to replace `<prefix>` with something that allows me to ignore the `_suffix.txt` part and browse any file on disk?

Comment: What do you mean by "path termination characters"?

Comment: Note that your Application Pool Identity (assuming IIS as a web server) is not supposed to have access to "any arbitrary file on disk", and by default hasn't.

Comment: You can check the filename with other Path methods to ensure it isn't invalid. Eg, [Path.IsPathRooted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.ispathrooted(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `true` if the argument is an absolute path.

Comment: will Path.ChangeExtension help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: 100% agree that the apppool account will not *should* not but how many times do people try to fix a problem by giving the application pool id more permissions than it needs. It will have access to configuration files and I am sure we have all seen the classic print.aspx?file=<pathtofile> display web.config file for printing out thus leaking connection strings.

Comment: @Ashley Pillay: I mean something that lets me input a specific file name and then terminate the query, thus ignoring the part that gets concatenated by the program. Something similar to how SQL Injection works.

Comment: @Paul-Jan: Unfortunately, we are in a situation where the default APP Pool identity needs to be replaced with a custom user account. That's why I'm even considering this scenario in the first place.

Comment: I don't suppose you could write the file path as a string and replace `<prefix>` by the `'*'` special character, later using the string or converting it for your methods, could you?

Comment: @Tiramonium: Let's assume I have no control over the code. I'm simply an attacker trying to exploit the code as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If filename (i.e. prefix) contains an absolute path, [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) will simply ignore the BaseDirectory. So *yes*, you can use it to browse arbitrary files, as long as those files end with _suffix.

There are no magic terminators to break off the string, as Path.Combine will throw an "Illegal characters in path" exception when it encounters non-standard characters.

**However**, permissions by default will not allow the Application Pool Identity access to any of those paths. So unless you changed these explicitly, this is not a security risk.

Comment: Except, the app pool account can't read arbitrary files. Only those stored in the site's directory.

Comment: OTOH we all know at least one junior dev that changed the account to `Administrator` to overcome "some .NET problem". Might even have been us

Comment: In the OPs case however, `fileName` _always_ ends in `_suffix.txt` - does that _still_ allow arbitrary files, even if the base directory is ignored?  The question is more about whether there's a certain character that could be injected to make it ignore the rest of the path (including the `_suffix.txt`), eg in a URL you could use `?` etc, and therefore get access to any file.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Correct, that's what I wrote in the comments as well. Expanded the answer to account for this. It is not what the question is about, but it is definitely something people looking for the answer need to be aware of :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Ah, good point, that might be the true gist of the question.

Comment: Another issue to bring up is Access Control.  In this application, can the user view ANY file that ends is the "suffix" or only a subset of them.  Can I view another user's files if I know/guess the filename?

Comment: @SBurris: Let's assume the API is misconfigured to run as admin.

Comment: @Tutor Based on that I would say there is a security concern, there is an Access Control issue.

Comment: @SBurris: I am very much aware of that. I'm trying to assess the kind of damage that can be caused since I have no control over how the users configure their website to run.